# Uploading a folder to Sharepoint using Python, on an O365 tenant with MFA

Tags: python, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, office365

I recently wrote a script that simply put, uploads a folder to sharepoint on my office365 tenant. For obvious reasons, the original auth was done using a service account that only had access to one document library. This worked fine:

```
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum import Site 
from shareplum.site import Version
import os 
import sys 

folderName = sys.argv[1]
authcookie = Office365('mySharepoint',username='username',password='password').GetCookies()
site= Site('mysharepoint/sites/mySite', version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)

for filename in os.listdir('myDir'):
    with open(foldername+"/"+filename, mode='rb') as file: 
        fileContent = file.read()
        folder.upload_file(fileContent,filename)
```

So under current basic auth, this works perfectly fine, it'll loop through whatever directory and upload all my files, be it text or jpgs, to my sharepoint.

Now the issue is, in production, everything is MFA, so basic auth won't work. I've tried app passwords, but despite flicking every setting applicable in Azure AD, the option simply doesn't exist.

Is there a simple way to allow this account to upload and go around MFA?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, you can use the Azure AD App-Only auth to access SharePoint then we can go through MFA. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) and [here](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/e625c177fa1c886d44b531bf0f4f75720cd915af)

For example

1. Create a certificate

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Creates a Self Signed Certificate for use in server to server authentication
.DESCRIPTION
.EXAMPLE
.\Create-SelfSignedCertificate.ps1 -CommonName "MyCert" -StartDate 2015-11-21 -EndDate 2017-11-21
This will create a new self signed certificate with the common name "CN=MyCert". During creation you will be asked to provide a password to protect the private key.
.EXAMPLE
.\Create-SelfSignedCertificate.ps1 -CommonName "MyCert" -StartDate 2015-11-21 -EndDate 2017-11-21 -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force)
This will create a new self signed certificate with the common name "CN=MyCert". The password as specified in the Password parameter will be used to protect the private key
.EXAMPLE
.\Create-SelfSignedCertificate.ps1 -CommonName "MyCert" -StartDate 2015-11-21 -EndDate 2017-11-21 -Force
This will create a new self signed certificate with the common name "CN=MyCert". During creation you will be asked to provide a password to protect the private key. If there is already a certificate with the common name you specified, it will be removed first.
#>
Param(

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string]$CommonName,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [DateTime]$StartDate,
   
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [DateTime]$EndDate,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Will overwrite existing certificates")]
   [Switch]$Force,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
   [SecureString]$Password
)

# DO NOT MODIFY BELOW

function CreateSelfSignedCertificate(){
    
    #Remove and existing certificates with the same common name from personal and root stores
    #Need to be very wary of this as could break something
    if($CommonName.ToLower().StartsWith("cn="))
    {
        # Remove CN from common name
        $CommonName = $CommonName.Substring(3)
    }
    $certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\my | Where-Object{$_.Subject -eq "CN=$CommonName"}
    if($certs -ne $null -and $certs.Length -gt 0)
    {
        if($Force)
        {
        
            foreach($c in $certs)
            {
                remove-item $c.PSPath
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "One or more certificates with the same common name (CN=$CommonName) are already located in the local certificate store. Use -Force to remove them";
            return $false
        }
    }

    $name = new-object -com "X509Enrollment.CX500DistinguishedName.1"
    $name.Encode("CN=$CommonName", 0)

    $key = new-object -com "X509Enrollment.CX509PrivateKey.1"
    $key.ProviderName = "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider"
    $key.KeySpec = 1
    $key.Length = 2048 
    $key.SecurityDescriptor = "D:PAI(A;;0xd01f01ff;;;SY)(A;;0xd01f01ff;;;BA)(A;;0x80120089;;;NS)"
    $key.MachineContext = 1
    $key.ExportPolicy = 1 # This is required to allow the private key to be exported
    $key.Create()

    $serverauthoid = new-object -com "X509Enrollment.CObjectId.1"
    $serverauthoid.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") # Server Authentication
    $ekuoids = new-object -com "X509Enrollment.CObjectIds.1"
    $ekuoids.add($serverauthoid)
    $ekuext = new-object -com "X509Enrollment.CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage.1"
    $ekuext.InitializeEncode($ekuoids)

    $cert = new-object -com "X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestCertificate.1"
    $cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(2, $key, "")
    $cert.Subject = $name
    $cert.Issuer = $cert.Subject
    $cert.NotBefore = $StartDate
    $cert.NotAfter = $EndDate
    $cert.X509Extensions.Add($ekuext)
    $cert.Encode()

    $enrollment = new-object -com "X509Enrollment.CX509Enrollment.1"
    $enrollment.InitializeFromRequest($cert)
    $certdata = $enrollment.CreateRequest(0)
    $enrollment.InstallResponse(2, $certdata, 0, "")
    return $true
}

function ExportPFXFile()
{
    if($CommonName.ToLower().StartsWith("cn="))
    {
        # Remove CN from common name
        $CommonName = $CommonName.Substring(3)
    }
    if($Password -eq $null)
    {
        $Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Password to protect private key" -AsSecureString
    }
    $cert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\my | where-object{$_.Subject -eq "CN=$CommonName"}
    
    Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -Password $Password -FilePath "$($CommonName).pfx"
    Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -Type CERT -FilePath "$CommonName.cer"
}

function RemoveCertsFromStore()
{
    # Once the certificates have been been exported we can safely remove them from the store
    if($CommonName.ToLower().StartsWith("cn="))
    {
        # Remove CN from common name
        $CommonName = $CommonName.Substring(3)
    }
    $certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\my | Where-Object{$_.Subject -eq "CN=$CommonName"}
    foreach($c in $certs)
    {
        remove-item $c.PSPath
    }
}

if(CreateSelfSignedCertificate)
{
    ExportPFXFile
    RemoveCertsFromStore
}
```

2. Register Azure AD application
   [image]
3. Configure API permissions.

```
SharePoint
     Application permissions
          Sites
             Sites.FullControl.All
```

3. Upload your `cer` file to Azure AD application. Regarding how to do that, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials#uploading-the-certificate-file)
4. Code

a. sdk

```
pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client
```

b. code

```
import os
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
site_url = "https://{your-tenant-prefix}.sharepoint.com"

cert_settings = {
    'client_id': '',
    'thumbprint': "6B36FBFC86FB1C019EB6496494B9195E6D179DDB",
    'certificate_path': '{0}/selfsigncert.cer'.format(os.path.dirname(__file__))
}


ctx = ClientContext(site_url ).with_client_certificate( "<azure ad tenant domain>",
                                                             cert_settings['client_id'],
                                                             cert_settings['thumbprint'],
                                                             cert_settings['certificate_path'])

target_url = "/Shared Documents"
target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(target_url)
size_chunk = 1000000
local_path = "<file path>"
file_size = os.path.getsize(local_path)
def print_upload_progress(offset):
    print("Uploaded '{}' bytes from '{}'...[{}%]".format(offset, file_size, round(offset / file_size * 100, 2)))
uploaded_file = target_folder.files.create_upload_session(local_path, size_chunk, print_upload_progress)
ctx.execute_query()
print('File {0} has been uploaded successfully'.format(uploaded_file.serverRelativeUrl))
```

Comment: This seems to make sense, however...

"<azure ad tenant domain>", this just the address of my o365? i..e. example.com

Also, this is triggering 


utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: I assume I have to fill in client_id with that applications client_id, same issue

Comment: @Jan.Jedrasik Regarding auth, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread